# How to balance scraper's usage of mobile proxy in the right way?

Tags: multithreading, web-scraping, proxy

I have a need to parse a certain website using different IP addresses. Mobile proxies were the best choice based on a certain set of factors - the target quite seriously blocks the parser by IP addresses.
The frequency of requests is relatively very high, which is why I have to change the output IP to a proxy every 5 minutes using a timer - anyone familiar with their essence will understand what I’m talking about.

What is the problem: changing IP = rebooting the mobile proxy modem. It follows from this that for 7-15 seconds it is out of network access.
My parser is multi-threaded, it launches about 50-70 instances once a second, each instance must go to the site, take information, write it to the database and die - each pass takes from 20 to 40 seconds, which is quite optimal, the code logic itself is almost optimized maximum.
We come down to the logic - if you give an instance a random proxy from the list, if it is unavailable, the instance will end with an error almost immediately. We cannot exclude the theory of probability, purely hypothetically - an accident could produce a dead proxy even during the entire 10 seconds that it is unavailable - and therefore we will lose 500-700 launches.

How can this be solved - install a “super proxy”, a transparent proxy, a balancing proxy - I’m not sure what exactly to call it, but the point is this - all instances connect to it, and under the hood it decides which proxy to issue, ideally - writes logs, collects statistics.
A product from Bright Data - Proxy Manager - fits this idea well; it implements exactly the functionality I’m talking about, but it’s true not fully and not very well. They have some problems with memory leaks, the software is developed in nodejs, and I suspect that there are other solutions.

Is there an analogue of this software, or is there a more adequate structure for such a system? Most likely, I just don’t understand what exactly such balancing software is called, so I can’t google similar software.
It can’t be that people invented proxies, but only one company invented a manager for them, and that one is crooked?)